# How to write a Matlab array as binary, and then read it in Fortran?

Tags: matlab, fortran, intel-fortran

I'm extremely new to both working on Linux and Fortran, so apologies if this is a basic question.

I am trying to firstly use fwrite to save a 60x150 array that I've produced in MATLAB as a binary file, which I am then attempting to load and read in Fortran as a 60x150 array again.

In Matlab, I have used the following code to save the array. In this case the name of the array in the workspace is VP, and I'm saving it to a file also called 'VP':

```matlab
>> fileID = fopen('VP','w');
>> fwrite(fileID,VP,'real*8');
>> fclose(fileID)
```

Next, I am copying the file over from Windows to a linux ssh server (I'm not sure if this is relevant, but thought it's worth including anything that might help).

Now, in my Fortran code, I've got:

```
REAL(KIND=kind(1.0D0)), DIMENSION(60,150) :: VP
...
open(unit, file="LOCATION/VP", access = "stream", form = "unformatted", iostat = stat)
  if(stat /= 0) labort("Failed to open input file")
print *, wl
DO inx2=1,60
 DO inx=1,150
  print *,inx
  READ(unit,*) VP(inx2,inx)
 ENDDO
ENDDO
   print *,VP(1:10,1)
```

Now, when I compile this there are no errors. However, when I run it, it gets to exactly the first "READ(unit,*) VP(inx2,inx)" before failing (you can tell from the print just before it).

I get the error:

```
forrtl: severe (257): formatted I/O to unit open for unformatted transfers, unit 111, file LOCATION/VP
```

Obviously I would like my actual result to be the function running and ending up with the same values in the array.

Now I've seen the question before, specifically for this error message, but that was answered by including `access="stream"` which I have already. Basically I am not sure at what point I am getting something wrong in this process, any help would be appreciated.

Note some things I have tried is changing the precision in fwrite, and swapping the inx2 and inx values around (but it fails on the first one so I don't believe that's the error).

Again this might be just a fundamental issue with my understanding of Fortran because I've been thrown in the deep end a bit with a project I'm working on (most of the code I'm running was produced by someone else, I'm just trying to edit a small part of it).

---

Edit:

Okay, thank you so much francescalus! He found the solution was to edit the line to READ(unit) VP(inx2,inx) in order to get it to run. However, the values I get by running the next line of code:

```
print *,VP(1:10,1)
```

Only the first value matches the first value in my original matlab array. Displaying VP(1:5,1:5) of the matlab array there aren't any other matching values. I might be able to figure this out on my own but as I'm already here I might as well ask as I haven't fully completed the original question (although got over a big hurdle!).

---

Edit 2:

Okay the next bit I've managed to figure out for myself. If anyone is searching though it was simply a case of swapping the DO loops. ie

```
DO inx=1,150
 DO inx2=1,60
  print *,inx
  READ(unit,*) VP(inx2,inx)
 ENDDO
ENDDO
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does it work with `READ(unit) VP(inx2,inx)` instead?

Comment: Oh my word, yes it does. Although, now I have the slight issue that VP(1:10,1) (just a check for correctness) in fortran is not the same as VP(1:10,1) or VP(1,1:10) in matlab, except for the first value.

Comment: The aspect of changing `read(unit,*)` to `read(unit)` is a common one (duplicates available), so it could be best if you edit the question to focus on the problem with `VP`'s values after that correction.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the question with the next issue. I do appreciate the help, and hopefully someone can help me with the next stage.

Comment: MATLAB's [fwrite](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fwrite.html) writes matrices in column order, and so does Fortran normally, but you are forcing Fortran to read it in row order. Note you can read the whole matrix in Fortran (in column order, then), with no loop: `read (unit) VP`. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order

Comment: If you're using `access=stream`, just read the file without `do` loops.  That is, do `read(unit) vp`.  This will likely be translated to a single IO operation rather than the inx*inx2 IO operations of the nested loops.